# Problems creating a payment

Tags: token, ico

I'm using the stellar lab to create a token. https://medium.com/@ashisherc/create-an-ico-on-stellar-network-with-custom-token-7b6aab349f33

When I get to the step to issue the token, I try to create a payment transaction between the issuing account and the distributing account and I get this error:

```
{
  "type": "https://stellar.org/horizon-errors/transaction_failed",
  "title": "Transaction Failed",
  "status": 400,
  "detail": "The transaction failed when submitted to the stellar network. The `extras.result_codes` field on this response contains further details.  Descriptions of each code can be found at: https://www.stellar.org/developers/learn/concepts/list-of-operations.html",
  "extras": {
    "envelope_xdr": "AAAAAIUy0VLXxhIkmU0z4CDYfEJU7K777oFxANDUM3zJxapdAAAAZAEouXUAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAEAAAAAfme+1L3KXfnc3u4FfRxfCDUpmkIXjlpYNtL1sR0Aq5QAAAABVE9UQQAAAACFMtFS18YSJJlNM+Ag2HxCVOyu++6BcQDQ1DN8ycWqXQAca/UmNAAAAAAAAAAAAALJxapdAAAAQC9IeBH5FTrD52meaw4w9EZVe5CbNZksnQGr628EAYoO20xuRYP7Csk6IRl3/JueguSe2UBTCllpydnD2phFgABdi3zAAAAAQJOrK+7VA8zjG/QgwX0rhY/KWe674AIuKtos6SPfe+jrQCZTt9T9DnJbinA6fdVGlkMvIjFj67d5UJKATJ4sMwI=",
    "result_codes": {
      "transaction": "tx_bad_auth_extra"
    },
    "result_xdr": "AAAAAAAAAGT////2AAAAAA=="
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This happens when there are unused signatures attached to the transaction. One scenario is when you have multiple signers and one signature with enough weight to process the transaction + plus another signature with extra weight (Which is not required)

for reference https://www.stellar.org/developers/guides/concepts/transactions.html

Answer (score 1):

`tx_bad_auth_extra` usually means you're submitting transactions to the wrong network.

Comment: Like Ashish mentions, strictly speaking it means that you have added signatures that are left unused.

Unless you are using multi-sig, this usually happens because the signature you added is signed for a different network from the one you're submitting to.

Testnet instead of public, or the other way around.